# How to retry on exception in destination transformer in Mirth

Tags: javascript, mirth

I have a channel that receives a message, extracts some information from it and then uses a destination transformer to enrich this information from external database and sends them to another channel.

The processing in the transformer is written in Javascript and it can sometimes fail when the message is ahead of the data in database. When this happens, I would like to wait a minute and try again.

For now, I am only throwing exception in the transformer that allows me to inspect the message. I tried to set the retry on destination, but it did not work. I have a feeling that only retries if the destination itself throws an error.

How can I retry when the destination transformer throws an exception?

Comment: To tackle problems like this in the past, I've tended to either create an in-memory, multi-threaded queuing mechanism with some Java (so that I can retry all of the messages all of the time, rather than having to wait for the first failure to clear up before working on the next), or creating a table in the Mirth DB for finer control of the queuing mechanism, using a JS Reader/Database Reader to re-process ResultSets of messages over a certain polling period.

Answer (score 0):

In your destination transformer wait for required amount of time and then route the same message back (router.routeMessageByChannelId) to the same channel (i.e., to the channel this destination belongs to) for re-processing. In order to do this you need to turn Source Queue of the Source Connector from OFF to ON.

Comment: How does the waiting work? If I put simply a delay to the javascript code, it seems that the whole processing stops - I need other messages to still go through. Could you give me an example how to reroute the message to the same channel in JavaScript?

Comment: I do not see your channel, I don't know how many destinations you have there. You may send your message to another channel that "sleeps" for a certain amount of time and sends the message back or something like that. To re-route a message you need something like this: router.routeMessageByChannelId(channelId, msg); Where channelId is a variable that contains, as it says, the current channel Id.